# Proper way for gradle to run a never ending task?

Tags: gradle

I'm using [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) to help reduce dependencies for my project. Gradlew is basically replacing grunt or gulp in my project. This makes java my only dependency.

Before, I'd use `npm run tsc` and I had an npm task that would run `tsc -w` but now that npm is a gradle plugin, I can't call npm directly. I have the following task in my build.gradle:

```
task watch(dependsOn: 'npmInstall', type: NpmTask) {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  args = ['run', 'tsc']
}
```

Technically it works. It first makes sure that the npm plugin has installed all it's pieces (including typescript) and then will run my tsc task. The problem is that `tsc -w` never terminates. It watches my files for changes until I choose to terminate it. It does this successfully, but gradle constantly reports that the task is `Building 75% > :watch`. I have another task in `package.json` that offers up my files in an `http-server` and it behaves in the same way.

Is there a preferred way to have gradle run a never ending task like this or should I just let it think it's perpetually building?

Comment: you probably can make use of the continuous mode in gradle that was introduced a couple releases ago: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#continuous_build